# What is the meaning of a null reference in composer.lock file?

Tags: json, composer-php, dependency-management

As far as I understand, Composer writes the list of the exact versions it installed into the `composer.lock` file.

The package `reference` attribute is used to store a specific commit number.

In some circumstances I see `null` values for `reference` attribute in my `composer.lock` file.

When does it happen? And what does it mean?

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to show such an example?

Answer (score 2):

By searching an example to paste to respond to @xabbuh's question I noticed that the null reference is always related to a `"type": "zip"` package, like shown below:

```
"dist": {
    "type": "zip",
    "url": "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-catalog-widget/magento-module-catalog-widget-100.0.5.0.zip",
    "~~,
    "shasum": "9824758cc690316a64727f823d33d752c9218c32"
},
```

So I guess that the answer to my question is that being the repository bound to a zip package there isn't any commit to refer to.